# How to "svn revert <file>" with Emacs Version Control?

Tags: version-control, vc, svn

How can I do a `svn revert <file>` from [Emacs Version Control](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl)?
I've read many parts of [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html#Version-Control), but can't find it.

I would like to do it over a file after opening it with `vc-directory` <kbd>C-x v d</kbd>, but any other way would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `M-x vc-revert`.

or use this function:

```
(defun revert-svn()
    (interactive)
    (vc-revert)
    (revert-buffer t t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x v u") 'revert-svn)
```

Comment: So, it seems that the wiki is wrong. With Emacs 24
I have `vc-revert` as `C-x v u`, and `vc-revert-buffer` with no keybinding.
Now, I'm not sure what does the `vc-revert-buffer` do...

Comment: Mmm, it seems it acts over the whole fileset, not just a file.
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Undo.html

Comment: `vc-revert-buffer` is obsolete since 23.1 and the fileset can be just a file.

Answer (score 1):

As @djangoliv has mentioned, `M-x vc-revert` works (<kbd>C-x v u</kbd> on Emacs 24.5.1).
When doing it over a file on a `*vc-dir*` buffer (opened by `vc-directory` command), another buffer with the differences is opened and a prompt message appears in the mini-buffer to confirm it.

Just like this image:

[image: vc-revert]